# Interrupt function in Arduino

Tags: arduino, sequence, led

I'm currently working on project which takes the button as input and when we click the button starting from the first LED it shifts and after each 0.5 seconds LEDs follow each other. Interrupt function works perfectly, but the problem is that interrupt works when the loop is finished. I want to turn of the LEDs when I click the button. How to solve this issue?

```cpp
int button;
void setup() {

 DDRD = B11110000;

 attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), buttonPressed, RISING);
}
void loop() {

  if(button) {

    PORTD = B00010000;
    delay(500);
    PORTD = PORTD <<1;
    delay(500);
    PORTD = PORTD <<1;
    delay(500);
    PORTD = PORTD <<1;
    delay(500);

  }
  else {

    PORTD = B00000000;

  }
}

void buttonPressed() {


  if(button == 0) {
    button = 1;
  }else {
    button = 0;
  }


}
```

Comment: huge community, no one knows.

Comment: Can you clarify? When pressing the button the firs time you want to turn on one light and once every .5 seconds switch which light is on? And when button is pressed again immediately turn all lights off?

Comment: When I press the button first LED should turn on, and after each .5 seconds it should shift to next LED and the previous one should turn off. LED sequence. everything works perfectly, but when I press the button to turn off the LEDs it waits till the loop finishes, and after that all LEDs turn off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing the whole loop you can rewrite the code to check the button state for each LED. This means that the LED will still always stay lit the full .5 second period.

```
int button;
void setup() {    
 DDRD = B11110000;    
 attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), buttonPressed, RISING);
}

void loop() {    
  if(button) {
    PORTD = PORTD <<1;
    if (PORTD == 0) {
        PORTD = B00010000;
    }
    delay(500);
  } else {    
    PORTD = B00000000;
  }
}

void buttonPressed() {    
  button = !button;
}
```

To make the LEDs dark immediately you should not use delay, but rather loop for up to .5 seconds and check the button state;

```
unsigned long timeout = millis() + 500;
while (button && millis() < timeout);
```

Or a bit more in context

```
void loop() {    
  if(button) {
    next_light();
    sleep(500);
  } else {    
    PORTD = B00000000;
  }
}

void next_light() {
  PORTD = PORTD <<1;
  if (PORTD == 0) {
    PORTD = B00010000;
  }
}

void sleep(unsigned long timeout) {
  unsigned long end = millis() + timeout;
  while (button && millis() < end);
}

void buttonPressed() {    
  button = !button;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments, but where should I use while loop?